# How to get Firefox 48 to search with Google from the URL bar?

Tags: firefox

My preferred search method is from the URL bar, because I can reach it by Ctrl+L (I dislike lifting my hands from the keyboard to use the mouse & use hotkeys as often as possible; I don't know of one to jump to the search box).

Suddenly, when I enter text there, FF searches with Bing.

How do I get it back to Google?

I have set Google, not Bing as a search engine in `settings` (in fact, I deleted Bing), and I know all three of add-ons, have been using them for years and have no reason to suspect them. Not do I have any additional toolbars.

I tried what (Google) searching suggested:
 - about:config
 - keyword.URL
 - I set it to `https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl`
 - I restarted FF, but still it searches with Bing :-(

I am virus free and ad-aware finds nothing suspicious.

I even completely uninstalled (with Revo, including registry entries and *all* files).

I do understand that Bing is FF's new search engine of choice - but how to I get my Google search from the URL back?

Answer (score 1):

Open Your Firefox browser, go to settings -> Search and select google as your search provider on the first drop down menu labeled default search engine

Comment: I had already done that. Sorry, I will update the question